# rmarkdown interactive time selector

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I often create chart reports on rstudio, knit it with rmarkdown and upload it to a private hosting account so I can share the document to be viewedas a webpage on a browser .

However those reports are static, therefore the viewer cannot, for example, select a time period he or she wishes to apply to the chart.

I wonder what would be the best solution, to add an interactive time selector to this rmarkdown document and make it work online.

I would really appreciate any advise for a quick and simple solution to this cenario.

Thanks

Comment: You can use shiny for this. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny.html for how to get started.

Comment: Hi DiceboyT, will it work online in a private server ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be honest. I know it doesn't work as an HTML file that you could send through email or whatever. I deploy all of my rmarkdown documents to a Shiny Server (so obviously shiny works there).

Comment: Ok, got it. tks.

Comment: [HTML widgets](https://www.htmlwidgets.org/) can be included in rmarkdown documents without the need for shiny, i.e. a server side R process.

Comment: Hi Ralf, looks like a simpler solution. I will look into it. Thanks.